# XSL get next value from node

Tags: xslt

how can i get next value from xml tree?

```
  List<Noeud> compteFacturation = new List<Noeud>();
        compteFacturation.Add(new Noeud("libelleCompteDeFacturation", "Compte N° 1"));
        compteFacturation.Add(new Noeud("nombreLigneTraitees", "10"));
        compteFacturation.Add(new Noeud("nombreLigneStatutOK", "19"));
        compteFacturation.Add(new Noeud("nombreLigneStatutKO", "11"));
        compteFacturations.Add(new Noeud("compteFacturation", compteFacturation));

        compteFacturation = new List<Noeud>();
        compteFacturation.Add(new Noeud("libelleCompteDeFacturation", "Compte N° 2"));
        compteFacturation.Add(new Noeud("nombreLigneTraitees", "26"));
        compteFacturation.Add(new Noeud("nombreLigneStatutOK", "25"));
        compteFacturation.Add(new Noeud("nombreLigneStatutKO", "24"));
        compteFacturations.Add(new Noeud("compteFacturation", compteFacturation));
```

when i put like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//compteFacturation/@libelleCompteDeFacturation" />
```

i got the first element

> Compte N° 1

how can i get the second one

> Compte N° 2

?

i have tried

```
<xsl:value-of select="//compteFacturation/@libelleCompteDeFacturation[position() = 2]" />
```

or

```
<xsl:value-of select="//compteFacturation/@libelleCompteDeFacturation/*[2]" />
```

i got nothing for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but your predicate selecting position is in the wrong place.

You want to select the `@libelleCompteDeFacturation` of the second `compteFacturation` element.

```
//compteFacturation[2]/@libelleCompteDeFacturation
```

Or if you are using XSLT 2.0 or greater, you could select the second item from the sequence of selected attributes (note the parethesis):

```
( //compteFacturation/@libelleCompteDeFacturation )[2]
```

With your other expressions:

```
//compteFacturation/@libelleCompteDeFacturation[position() = 2]
```

is attempting to select all of the attributes who's position is 2, but an element can only have one attribute with that name so it will never have more than 1.

And with this expression:

```
//compteFacturation/@libelleCompteDeFacturation/*[2]
```

You were asking for the second child element of the `@libelleCompteDeFacturation` attribute. An attribute can't have child elements, so this will never select anything.